# non-advancing WRITE...but not intentionally?

Tags: file-io, fortran

I have a brief snippet of code from a Fortran 95 program that should, in theory, spit out my results into some text files.  It would be convenient, for readability if nothing else, for the data to be written in columns (so, one column for variable X, one for Y, etc.).  In the first set of WRITE commands below (i.e., those associated with the first OPEN command), the idea is to have a text identifier for the user to read, followed by a numeric value.  In the second write command, I just dump out four columns of data, each specific to a given variable.

```
open(unit=10,file='outs_sum.txt',status='replace')
do i=1,1
    write(10,'(a12,f5.4)') 'Min. sigma: ',sigma_low
    end do
    do i=1,1
    write(10,'(a12,f5.4)') 'Max. sigma: ',sigma_high
    end do
    write(10,'(a11,f5.4)') 'Sigma inc: ',0.005
    write(10,*) '# of sigmas: ',ii
    write(10,'(a9,f5.1)') 'Min. DL: ',dl_low
    write(10,'(a9,f5.1)') 'Max. DL: ',dl_high
    write(10,*) 'DL inc: ',1
    write(10,*) '# of DLs: ',i
    write(10,*) 'Total rows: ',(i*ii)
close(unit=10)

open(unit=10,file='outs.txt',status='replace')
    do i=1,dls
        do ii=1,sigmas
            write(10,*) gtow_out(i,ii),ctsig_out(i,ii),sigout(i,ii),dlout(i,ii)
        end do
    end do
close(unit=10)
```

However, what happens on the output side is this: the latter WRITE does exactly what I'd expect and spits out the data in column form...but the former insists on writing everything to the same row.  At least when I open things in Notepad.  If I use GVIM, it looks as it should.

**Why does the first set of WRITE commands write to the same row, and how can I force it to insert a line break after each command instead?  Alternatively, is Notepad just showing me something that isn't really there?**

Comment: Don't use the Code snippet functionality. It does not work for Fortran.

Comment: As GVIM depicts it as intended, I would assume a Notepad bug. Maybe some issue with Unix/Windows line endings. Don't use Notepad.

Comment: Alright.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes--I write it in Ubuntu and am reading out in Windows.

Comment: `Notepad` definitely needs windows `cr/lf` line endings.  Many other windows apps do not including even  `WordPad`.  Of course if you need windows endings you can do that but its a different question.